# My (hidden) tab doesn't want to open when clicking on the hamburger button

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble with my responsive navbar, I've hidden the inside-menu(li's) and want it to open when I click on the menu(hamburger) but it's not working. Can someone please help me?

```js
const menuButton = document.getElementById('menu-button');
const insideMenu = document.getElementById('inside-menu');

menuButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  insideMenu.classList.menuButton('active');
});
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
    <div class="menu" id="menu-button">
        <a href="#" class="Menu">
        <img src="menu.png" alt="menu"></a>
        <ul id="inside-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classlit has methods: add(), remove(), replace(), and toggle().
classList.menuButton does not exist, that's where the error comes from.

To solve your problem you can use the toggle() method like this:

```js
const menuButton = document.getElementById('menu-button');
const insideMenu = document.getElementById('inside-menu');

menuButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  insideMenu.classList.toggle('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
    <div class="menu" id="menu-button">
        <a href="#" class="Menu">
        <img src="menu.png" alt="menu"></a>
        <ul id="inside-menu" class="hidden">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```